Argument Principle for poles at infinity
From Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences by M. Boas (3rd ed., p. 695): Show that $f(z)=z^3+4z+1$ has exactly one zero in the first quadrant.
The solution uses the Argument Principle to show that the winding number is 1 in the first quadrant. However, the solution does not consider the pole of third order at infinity for  $f(z)$. How should one consider poles at infinity within the domain of the first quadrant, and how is the result (number of zeros - number of poles) modified in this case ?

Infinity is not "within the domain of the first quadrant", so one should not consider it. The result uses a family of bounded contours to derive the result. For any point in the first quadrant (again, that does not include $\infty$), there is a contour in the family that includes it, thus, the existence of a second zero in the first quadrant is ruled out. If one wishes to use the Riemann sphere instead and just use its boundary as the contour, note that $\infty$ is on that boundary, which makes the Argument Principle inapplicable.

Thank you. If I understand you correctly, the argument principle is not applicable to the point at infinity.

No. The argument principle is applicable to any point on the Riemann sphere that is encircled by the contour, but does not lie on the contour. In this case, the point at infinity lies on the contour, so that is why the principle does not apply. The same thing is true for any point.

But there is a consideration to be made here. Normally for a simple closed curve, we consider its interior to be the side that is bounded - i.e., the side that does not contain the point at infinity. By this idea, there can be no curve that encircles $\infty$. But on a sphere, there is no particular reason to choose one side of the curve over the other. The argument principle applies to both sides. The difference between pole and zero counts is the same on each side, though the signs flip, as the contour is CCW around one side, and CW around the other.

Isnt there a one-one correspondence between points on a Riemann sphere and the complex plane ? In this case, one could apply the transformation z=1/t, and use the argument principle in the limit t goes to zero, for a simple closed curve that encloses the origin...

Adding a single point $\infty$ to an infinite set $\Bbb C$ does indeed leave it in one-to-one correspondence with the original. That is what "infinite" means. However such correspondences are not even continuous, much less helpful analytically. $\frac 1z$ fails to be a one-one correspondence, as no point in $\Bbb C$ is mapped to $0$ in the Riemann sphere. But $\frac 1z$ does map closed curves not passing thru $0$ to closed curves not passing through $\infty$, which, as I said, can be considered to encircle $\infty$. Yet they can also be considered to encircle their other side.

I would like to give a full answer to this question since it is a standard application of the argument principle and is worth fully comprehending for future work. The argument principle states:
Suppose $f$ is meromorphic in a region $\Omega$ with zeros $\left\{z_j\right\}$ and poles $\left\{p_k\right\}$. Suppose $\gamma$ is a cycle with $\gamma \sim 0$ in $\Omega$ (i.e. $\gamma$ is homologous to 0 in $\Omega$), and suppose $\left\{z_j\right\} \cap \gamma=\emptyset$ and $\left\{p_k\right\} \cap \gamma=\emptyset$. Then
$$
n(f(\gamma), 0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z=\sum_j n\left(\gamma, z_j\right)-\sum_k n\left(\gamma, p_k\right),$$
where $n(.,.)$ is the winding number. The winding number is defined as follows
If $\gamma$ is a cycle, then the index or winding number of $\gamma$ about a  is
$$
n(\gamma, a)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{d \zeta}{\zeta-a},
$$
for $a \notin \gamma$. We have that $\gamma \sim 0$ is the same as $n( \gamma , a) = 0$ for all $a\notin \gamma$. One can show that the winding number of a cycle around a point a is the change in argument of the cycle around the point. Note that if $\gamma$ has winding number $1$ around each zero and pole then the right-hand side is simply the number of zeros minus the number of poles.
We let $\gamma$ be the contour consisting of the horizontal line segment extending from 0 to $R$, which we label $\gamma_1$, the quarter circle of radius $R$ going from $R$ to $iR$, which we label $\gamma_2$ and the vertical line segment from $iR$ to $0$ which we label $\gamma_3$; in total we have $\gamma=\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2 \cup \gamma_3.$
We note firstly that $f(z)$ has no roots on the positive part of the imaginary axis. We also see that it has no roots on the positive part of the. In addition, we have that for a large enough $R$, the contour $\gamma$ will contain all of the zeros of $f(z)$ that lie in the first quadrant. So let $R$ be large enough to contain all the zeros of $f$ in the first quadrant. We will now apply the argument principle to $f$ on $\gamma$. Note we can do this since $f$ has no roots on $\gamma$. In addition, since $f$ has no poles inside of this contour we have by the argument principle
$$
n(f(\gamma), 0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z=\sum_j n\left(\gamma, z_j\right)=\text{#number of zeros in first quadrant}.$$
Note that the right-hand side is independent of $R$ for large enough $R$, so we can take $R$ to infinity without affecting the right-hand side.
On $\gamma_1$ we have that $f(x)=x^3+4x+1$ and clearly the argument does not change.
On $\gamma_2$ we can calculate the winding number in two ways. Firstly, we look at the change in the argument. On $\gamma_2$ we have that $z=Re^{it}$ and $0 \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. We have
$$f(Re^{it})=R^3e^{i3t}+4Re^{it}+1=R^3\cos(3t)+4R\cos(t)+1+ i(R^3\sin(3t)+4R\sin(t)).$$ For very large R we have that we have that the terms with $R^3$ will dominate and we will have
$$R^3\cos(3t)+4R\cos(t)+1+ i(R^3\sin(3t)+4R\sin(t))\sim R^3\cos(3t)+1+ iR^3\sin(3t).$$
As $t$ goes from $t=0$ to $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ the change in argument will then be $3\frac{\pi}{2}-3\cdot 0=\frac{3\pi}{2}.$\
Another way to see this this is to calculate directly
$$ \int_\gamma \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z= i\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(3R^2e^{2it}+4)Re^{it}}{R^3e^{3it}+4Re^{it}+1} d t\to i\frac{3\pi}{2}$$
as $R\to \infty$; note that the i disappears when we divide by $\frac{1}{2\pi i}.$
On $\gamma_3$ we have $z=it$ for $0\leq t\leq R$ and $f(it)=i(4t-t^3)+1$. We see that $\arg(f(iR))=\arg(i(4R-R^3)+1)\to -\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $R\to \infty$ and that $\arg(f(0))=0$ and thus the total change in argument in $\pi/2$.
I want to stress again a part of the calculation which seems to cause confusion. The argument principle says
$$
n(f(\gamma), 0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z=\sum_j n\left(\gamma, z_j\right)$$
where $\gamma$ is the contour from before. We note that for large enough $R>0$, the right-hand side is constant and is equal to the number of zeros in the first quadrant, in particular it is independent of $R$ if $R$ is chosen large enough. We can therefore choose $R$ sufficiently large (i.e. taking the limit as $R$ is sufficiently large) when calculating the left-hand side since it should be constant (because the right-hand side is) for $R$ large enough.
In total we get
$$n(f(\gamma),0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z=\frac{1}{2\pi} \left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$$
which completes the result.

Thank you for the detailed answer. My query pertained to the applicability of the argument principle to the point at infinity. Could you please address this point in your response ?

Yes, absolutely. That is exactly what I tried to highlight in the answer. We know that there exists a certain $R$ large enough such that the quarter circle that lies in the first quadrant covers all zeros of $f$ in the first quadrant. Inside of this contour there are only zeros of $f$ and no poles. So you are not actually integrating over the entire first quadrant, but a large enough quarter circle to cover all zeros and no poles.
